# Hazelcast Predicate on Key

Tags: hazelcast

I have a IMap which contains `String` key and `Foo` value object.

```
IMap<String, String> mapTest1 = client.getMap("testMap");

Foo foo1 = new Foo();
Foo foo2 = new Foo();
Foo foo3 = new Foo();
Foo foo4 = new Foo();

mapTest1.put( "somePrefix1:abc:testKey1", foo1);
mapTest1.put( "somePrefix3:abc:testKey2", foo2);
mapTest1.put( "somePrefix4:def:testKey3", foo3);
mapTest1.put( "somePrefix5:def:testKey4", foo4);
```

I want to get `foo1` and `foo2` in a `List` when I give `"abc"` as an input.

Also I want to get only `foo1` in a `List` when I give `"somePrefix1"` and `"abc"` as an input.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the key with `__key` and combine it with a `LIKE` predicate.

So this perhaps as  `__key LIKE "%abc%"` using [3.*](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12/javadoc/com/hazelcast/query/SqlPredicate.html) or [4.*](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.0/javadoc/com/hazelcast/query/Predicates.html)

On new style SQL, BETA from 4.1, `SELECT this FROM mapname WHERE __key LIKE '%abc%'`